# POST function on server returns undefined

Tags: javascript, post, sveltekit

i have a frontend where I define a string in this case `videoLink`.
Besides that I have an async function that starts when a button is clicked.

```
//sveltekit

async function addToQueue(){
        console.log(videoLink);
        const res = await fetch('/tool/server', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                videoData: videoLink
            }
        })
        
        const json = await res.json()
        console.log(json);
        videoLink = "";
    }
```

This function sends an http-post request with fetch to my server.js file.

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').RequestHandler} */

export async function POST(event) {
  const data = await event.request.body;
  const link = data.videoData;
  console.log(link)
}
```

when i run the post-request (by clicking the Button in my frontend), my server logs `undefined`. As far as I know the server gets the POST request, because it logs only if I click the button.

But why does it return `undefined`? I have tried to parse the json, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me? What is wrong with my JSON?

Comment: _What_ JSON ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Examine the Request payload you are sending:

> ```
> [object Object]
> ```

`fetch` doesn't support plain objects for the `body` option. It will convert them to strings with their `toString()` method.

You need to either provide:

- an object which `fetch` does support. The common options are

  - [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data
  - [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for `multipart/form-data`
- an encoded string (such as the output of `JSON.stringify`) **and** also set the `content-type` HTTP request header to match

---

Which you choose will depend on what encodings the server side code supports.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination.

Comment: I have changed my js code in svelte to this

Comment: async function addToQueue(){
  console.log(videoLink);
  const res = await fetch('/tool/server', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
    videoData: videoLink
   })
  })
  
  const json = await res.json()
  console.log(json);
  videoLink = "";
 }

Comment: But I still receive a 500 server error

Comment: no, I set it to 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Answer (score 0):

So I have provided

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

to fetch the data.

On the server side I've done  the following:

```
export async function POST({request}) {
  const data = await request.json()
  console.log(data)
  return {}
}
```

Now the function returns `{}`, which isn't mandatory. The reason it works now is that POST gets `{request}` as an argument.
Notice the curly braces. Thanks a lot to [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) for his help.